# Brackets.io editor - Save Editor Config to git

Tags: adobe-brackets

Is there a way to save the configuration of my brackets editor to git?

The [brackets preferences docs](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Preferences-System) don't seem to indicate a way to do this yet.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets stores your preferences as JSON. The location of the file depends on the *preference scope*:

**User-global preferences**

- Your default settings
- Located at `%BRACKETS_APPDATA%/brackets.json`

**Project-level preferences**

- Overrides any number of preferences on a project-specific basis
- Located at the root of your current project as `.brackets.json`